# Does there exist a sequence of groups whose representation theory is described by plane partitions?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, young-tableaux

More precisely, does there exist a sequence $G_1 < G_2 < \cdots$ of finite groups such that the irreducible representations of $G_n$ are parameterized by the plane partitions of total size $n$?

Comment: I take it this is supposed to be by analogy with the representation theory of the symmetric group? (But it may not be too useful to point this out; anybody who doesn't recognize that isn't going to be able to help.)

Comment: You'd probably like to have the analogue of the branching rule hold as well, I imagine.

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal.  

Comment: More generally, what are some objects naturally parameterized by plane partitions? I ask this question, because ordinary partitions seems to be a ubiquitous index set.

Comment: A relevant paper is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.5310.pdf.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not if you want the direct analogue of the branching rule to hold: namely, if V is the representation of G<sub>n</sub> corresponding to a plane partition A of n, then the restriction of V to G<sub>n-1</sub> is the direct sum of one copy of the representation corresponding to each plane partition of n-1 contained in A.  That would allow you to compute the dimension of the representation corresponding to A as the number of paths in the containment poset of plane partitions from the empty partition to A.  Some computation then shows that the order of G<sub>3</sub> would be 1+4+4+1+4+1=15, but there's only one group of order 15, the abelian one, which doesn't work.

You could imagine some variations of the branching rule, though, such as "if B is obtained from A by replacing k by k-1 then the irrep corresponding to A contains k copies of the irrep corresponding to B", and maybe something like that would work.